# How can I make a function with 3 parameter to make an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I wrote this:

```
function create(arr,start,end)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < end ; i++)
    {
        arr = start++;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What do you want it to do? In other words, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If `arr` is an array, you can't use `arr = start++`, you should at least use `arr[i] = start++`. Anyway, you should explain better what you are trying to do

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you want an array of `end` size or do you wan part of `arr` from `start` to `end` or ... your question has too many ambiguity, please explain!

Comment: I want to make a function that take 3 parameters. an empty array, a number for start and a number for the end of the array. Then, pass 3 arguments to this function to make an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(arr, start, end) {
  for(var i = 0; i < end ; i++) {
    arr.push( start+i );
  }
  return arr;
}
```